# Trying to get light to follow object along z-axis, without rotation

Tags: animation, constraints, tracking

I'm simply trying to get a Spot light to follow my animating character, the character moves along the z-axis, and I would like the spot light to follow the character at a constrained distance away, higher up on the same z-axis.

I've already tried the *Track To* constraint, but that's not what I'm looking for, as it simply rotates the light to face the character, rather than maintaining a specified distance away on the z-axis.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: *Track To* constraint is the wrong one, it is for pointing one object at another. Try the *Copy Location* constraint instead, and tick the *Offset* option

Comment: Or make the light a child of the character using  **Child Of** constraint.

Comment: @Ramos: I suggest you write an answer